# Where do resource files go when developing Mac apps?

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm new to developing Mac OSX apps via Delphi (Berlin) and don't know where to put resource files. In Windows I can write `ImageControl1.LoadFromFile('aFile.png');` and know that's referencing the directory where my executable is located. Or I can do something like make and reference the path to a separate directory where I'm putting resources.

But I don't know where to put resources or how their paths work when developing on a Windows machine for an app that'll be compiled and run on a Mac. I tried putting an image file in the Delphi project's OSX subdirectory as well as entering a complete path, i.e., LoadFromFile('path/goes/here'). I also tried using forward and backward slashes in the path name expression. In each case I got an error (when compiling for Mac, not Windows). I'm sort of thinking the files should live on the Mac somewhere...but I'm lost.

I'm hoping someone could tell me where to put these kinds of resource files, or how to properly reference them, when developing Mac apps on a Windows machine (or, alternatively, a good reference or two that'll explain it to me ... I looked online but couldn't find an answer).

Comment: I believe you can embed resources into the app on OS-X the same as how Windows works - the method I think should be the exact same for the two. Just look into Embedded Resources, specifically by using an `rc` file.

Comment: "know that's referencing the directory where my executable is located". Er, wrong. It's relative to the current directory. Which may be the directory where the exe is, or it may not be. So that's the first thing to fix. Use an absolute path. Or an embedded resource.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan -- I'll leave the post as is, but your point is well taken. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, on the Mac, resources are located in the Resources branch (subdirectory) of the `.app` "file", which is in fact similar to a directory with branches for resources and one for the executable. AFAIK, Delphi knows this (can't check currently, my Mac is in repair) and produces the correct `.app` structure. ISTM that you should do the same as on Windows, i.e. **simply add the resource to the project** and Delphi will do its thing. How it does that is irrelevant.

Comment: Overview of bundle directories: [Placing content in a bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle)

Answer (score 1):

There's some info about the structure of macOS app bundles, here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW19

In the Delphi Deployment Manager, resources can be deployed to a remote path of:

Contents\Resources\

And subfolders thereof. The following code should return the root of the .app package:

```
NSStrToStr(TNSBundle.Wrap(TNSBundle.OCClass.mainBundle).bundlePath)
```

Add /Contents/Resources (and applicable subfolders) to that path, and you can load the deployed files from there